# SQL to get Latest Objects

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle table that has a PK of object_id, and another field called system_id.  The system_id can occur multiple times and acts as a Master to associate multiple versions of an object.

What I need to do is retrieve the latest object_id for each system_id in the table.  I can assume that the largest object_id will always be the latest, so I can use the MAX function.  My problem is doing this for each system_id.  Maybe I need to write PL/SQL instead of a basic SQL query?  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just use MAX and GROUP BY ?

```
SELECT 
   MAX(object_id) as maxObjectId
   --, system_id
FROM table
GROUP BY system_id
```